# Python implementation of Jenkins Hash?

Tags: python, hash

Does there exist a native Python implementation of the [Jenkins hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html) algorithm(s)?

I need a hash algorithm that takes an arbitrary string and turns it into an 32-bit integer. For a given string, it must guarantee to return the same integer across platforms.

I have looked at the ELF hash algorithm, of which I have found a Python implementation. Could this be a suitable replacement given the above criteria? (http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/#ELFHashFunction)

Answer (score 14):

This native python-code should give you the same hash as the original lookup3.c

```
# Need to constrain U32 to only 32 bits using the & 0xffffffff
# since Python has no native notion of integers limited to 32 bit
# http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

'''Original copyright notice:
    By Bob Jenkins, 1996.  bob_jenkins@burtleburtle.net.  You may use this
    code any way you wish, private, educational, or commercial.  Its free.
'''

def rot(x,k):
    return (((x)<<(k)) | ((x)>>(32-(k))))

def mix(a, b, c):
    a &= 0xffffffff; b &= 0xffffffff; c &= 0xffffffff
    a -= c; a &= 0xffffffff; a ^= rot(c,4);  a &= 0xffffffff; c += b; c &= 0xffffffff
    b -= a; b &= 0xffffffff; b ^= rot(a,6);  b &= 0xffffffff; a += c; a &= 0xffffffff
    c -= b; c &= 0xffffffff; c ^= rot(b,8);  c &= 0xffffffff; b += a; b &= 0xffffffff
    a -= c; a &= 0xffffffff; a ^= rot(c,16); a &= 0xffffffff; c += b; c &= 0xffffffff
    b -= a; b &= 0xffffffff; b ^= rot(a,19); b &= 0xffffffff; a += c; a &= 0xffffffff
    c -= b; c &= 0xffffffff; c ^= rot(b,4);  c &= 0xffffffff; b += a; b &= 0xffffffff
    return a, b, c

def final(a, b, c):
    a &= 0xffffffff; b &= 0xffffffff; c &= 0xffffffff
    c ^= b; c &= 0xffffffff; c -= rot(b,14); c &= 0xffffffff
    a ^= c; a &= 0xffffffff; a -= rot(c,11); a &= 0xffffffff
    b ^= a; b &= 0xffffffff; b -= rot(a,25); b &= 0xffffffff
    c ^= b; c &= 0xffffffff; c -= rot(b,16); c &= 0xffffffff
    a ^= c; a &= 0xffffffff; a -= rot(c,4);  a &= 0xffffffff
    b ^= a; b &= 0xffffffff; b -= rot(a,14); b &= 0xffffffff
    c ^= b; c &= 0xffffffff; c -= rot(b,24); c &= 0xffffffff
    return a, b, c

def hashlittle2(data, initval = 0, initval2 = 0):
    length = lenpos = len(data)

    a = b = c = (0xdeadbeef + (length) + initval)

    c += initval2; c &= 0xffffffff

    p = 0  # string offset
    while lenpos > 12:
        a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24)); a &= 0xffffffff
        b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24)); b &= 0xffffffff
        c += (ord(data[p+8]) + (ord(data[p+9])<<8) + (ord(data[p+10])<<16) + (ord(data[p+11])<<24)); c &= 0xffffffff
        a, b, c = mix(a, b, c)
        p += 12
        lenpos -= 12

    if lenpos == 12: c += (ord(data[p+8]) + (ord(data[p+9])<<8) + (ord(data[p+10])<<16) + (ord(data[p+11])<<24)); b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24)); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 11: c += (ord(data[p+8]) + (ord(data[p+9])<<8) + (ord(data[p+10])<<16)); b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24)); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 10: c += (ord(data[p+8]) + (ord(data[p+9])<<8)); b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24)); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 9:  c += (ord(data[p+8])); b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24)); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 8:  b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24)); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 7:  b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16)); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 6:  b += ((ord(data[p+5])<<8) + ord(data[p+4])); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24))
    if lenpos == 5:  b += (ord(data[p+4])); a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24));
    if lenpos == 4:  a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24))
    if lenpos == 3:  a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16))
    if lenpos == 2:  a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8))
    if lenpos == 1:  a += ord(data[p+0])
    a &= 0xffffffff; b &= 0xffffffff; c &= 0xffffffff
    if lenpos == 0: return c, b

    a, b, c = final(a, b, c)

    return c, b

def hashlittle(data, initval=0):
    c, b = hashlittle2(data, initval, 0)
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    hashstr = 'Four score and seven years ago'
    hash, hash2 = hashlittle2(hashstr, 0xdeadbeef, 0xdeadbeef)
    print '"%s": %x %x' % (hashstr, hash, hash2)

    hash = hashlittle(hashstr, 0)
    print '"%s": %x' % (hashstr, hash)
```

Comment: Amazing!, works perfectly, I tested against my local c implementation of the same hash, thanks a lot!, you saved me a ton of work :)

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the first 32 bits of an md5sum

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> unpack("<IIII",md5("thestring").digest())[0]
1515985217
```

Comment: Normally MD5 is avoided for speed reasons unless you *really* need a cryptographic hash.   But of course the C library implementation of MD5 will likely beat the pure Python implementation of the above algorithm by a far margin!

Answer (score 4):

Ended up implementing it on my own. Released according to the original copyright notice (see below). Use at your own risk and have fun :-)

```
'''Implements a straight Jenkins lookup hash - http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html

Usage: 
    from jhash import jhash
    print jhash('My hovercraft is full of eels')

Returns: unsigned 32 bit integer value

Prereqs: None

Tested with Python 2.6.
Version 1.00 - der@dod.no - 23.08.2010

Partly based on the Perl module Digest::JHash
http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Digest-JHash-0.06/lib/Digest/JHash.pm

Original copyright notice:
    By Bob Jenkins, 1996.  bob_jenkins@burtleburtle.net.  You may use this
    code any way you wish, private, educational, or commercial.  It's free.

    See http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/evahash.html
    Use for hash table lookup, or anything where one collision in 2^^32 is
    acceptable.  Do NOT use for cryptographic purposes.
'''

def mix(a, b, c):
    '''mix() -- mix 3 32-bit values reversibly.
For every delta with one or two bits set, and the deltas of all three
  high bits or all three low bits, whether the original value of a,b,c
  is almost all zero or is uniformly distributed,
* If mix() is run forward or backward, at least 32 bits in a,b,c
  have at least 1/4 probability of changing.
* If mix() is run forward, every bit of c will change between 1/3 and
  2/3 of the time.  (Well, 22/100 and 78/100 for some 2-bit deltas.)'''
    # Need to constrain U32 to only 32 bits using the & 0xffffffff 
    # since Python has no native notion of integers limited to 32 bit
    # http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex
    a &= 0xffffffff; b &= 0xffffffff; c &= 0xffffffff
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>13); a &= 0xffffffff
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<8); b &= 0xffffffff
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>13); c &= 0xffffffff
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>12); a &= 0xffffffff
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<16); b &= 0xffffffff
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>5); c &= 0xffffffff
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= (c>>3); a &= 0xffffffff
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= (a<<10); b &= 0xffffffff
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= (b>>15); c &= 0xffffffff
    return a, b, c

def jhash(data, initval = 0):
    '''hash() -- hash a variable-length key into a 32-bit value
  data    : the key (the unaligned variable-length array of bytes)
  initval : can be any 4-byte value, defaults to 0
Returns a 32-bit value.  Every bit of the key affects every bit of
the return value.  Every 1-bit and 2-bit delta achieves avalanche.'''
    length = lenpos = len(data)

    # empty string returns 0
    if length == 0:
        return 0

    # Set up the internal state
    a = b = 0x9e3779b9 # the golden ratio; an arbitrary value
    c = initval        # the previous hash value
    p = 0              # string offset

    # ------------------------- handle most of the key in 12 byte chunks
    while lenpos >= 12:
        a += (ord(data[p+0]) + (ord(data[p+1])<<8) + (ord(data[p+2])<<16) + (ord(data[p+3])<<24))
        b += (ord(data[p+4]) + (ord(data[p+5])<<8) + (ord(data[p+6])<<16) + (ord(data[p+7])<<24))
        c += (ord(data[p+8]) + (ord(data[p+9])<<8) + (ord(data[p+10])<<16) + (ord(data[p+11])<<24))
        a, b, c = mix(a, b, c)
        p += 12
        lenpos -= 12

    # ------------------------- handle the last 11 bytes
    c += length
    if lenpos >= 11: c += ord(data[p+10])<<24
    if lenpos >= 10: c += ord(data[p+9])<<16
    if lenpos >= 9:  c += ord(data[p+8])<<8
    # the first byte of c is reserved for the length
    if lenpos >= 8:  b += ord(data[p+7])<<24
    if lenpos >= 7:  b += ord(data[p+6])<<16
    if lenpos >= 6:  b += ord(data[p+5])<<8
    if lenpos >= 5:  b += ord(data[p+4])
    if lenpos >= 4:  a += ord(data[p+3])<<24
    if lenpos >= 3:  a += ord(data[p+2])<<16
    if lenpos >= 2:  a += ord(data[p+1])<<8
    if lenpos >= 1:  a += ord(data[p+0])
    a, b, c = mix(a, b, c)

    # ------------------------- report the result
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    hashstr = 'My hovercraft is full of eels'
    myhash = jhash(hashstr)
    print 'jhash("%s"): %d' % (hashstr, myhash)
```

Comment: This implements Jenkins hash lookup2, for reference, so people don't get confused.

Answer (score 2):

a simple implementation form the [one_at_a_time hash given at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function). Mind this algorithm has an avalanche behavior.

```
def getJenkinHash(ba : bytearray):
    hash : int = 0
    for i in range(len(ba)):
        hash += ba[i]
        hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF
        hash += hash << 10
        hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF
        hash ^= hash >> 6
        hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    hash += hash << 3
    hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    hash ^= hash >> 11
    hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    hash += hash << 15
    hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    return hash
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a ["jenkins" package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkins/1.0.2) on PyPi. But it is not "native" as the core implementation is in C.

Comment: Yes, I've found it, but I get error messages about some missing .bat-file when I try to install it on Windows. I'm looking for a solution with a minimal amount of prerequisites.

Comment: The Jenkins 1.0.2 PyPi package fails building on Linux too with "OSError: /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lookup3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Here a minimal implementation:

```
def hash(x):
    """ Jenkins Hash 32bits."""
    x = (x + int('7ed55d16', 16)) + (x << 12)
    x = (x ^ int('c761c23c', 16)) ^ (x >> 19)
    x = (x + int('165667b1', 16)) + (x << 5)
    x = (x + int('d3a2646c', 16)) ^ (x << 9)
    x = (x + int('fd7046c5', 16)) + (x << 3)
    x = (x ^ int('b55a4f09', 16)) ^ (x >> 16)
    return x
```